# Select data from Excel Workbook which is not in an Access Table

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have an Access table. The fields match the fields of an Excel Workbook. The Access table contains some records that the Excel worksheet doesn't have, and vice versa. However, there is some overlap. Example:

Access Table1

```
ID        Name      Attribute
1         Canada    A
2         USA       B
3         Mexico    A
```

Excel

```
Name      Attribute
USA       B
Mexico    A
France    B
```

The data that is present in Excel, but not Access, should be added to the Access table. Expected output:

```
ID        Name      Attribute
1         Canada    A
2         USA       B
3         Mexico    A
4         France    B
```

Right now, I open a Recordset on an Excel Worksheet. I would like to execute a query similar to

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Attribute)
SELECT (Name, Attribute) FROM Recordset
WHERE (Name, Attribute) NOT IN 
      (SELECT Name, Attribute FROM Table1)
```

Is it possible to do so in Access? How do I refer to my recordset? Here is the code leading up to the question:

```
Sub openWorksheet()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim lastRowIndex As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbPath As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset



    wbPath = "C:\Users\david.grandmaison\Desktop\RISE\Rise_Template.xlsx"
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & wbPath & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    strQuery = "SELECT Dist_Ret_Door_ID FROM [Sheet1$]"
    rs1.Open strQuery, cn     

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strQuery = "This is what I'm trying to write"
    db.Execute strQuery
```

*I know I could loop on the Excel recordset and check each record one by one, and add it if it doesn't exist, but I am looking for a single insert as looping will take too long. However if I'm wrong or if there is not way to avoid it please let me know.*

Comment: Cannot use a recordset in a query. Sounds like should be able to set a link to the Excel sheet then treat the linked sheet like a table (except cannot edit the data).

Comment: Then you might search on the topic "SQL Upsert".

Comment: Use [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) to create a link to an Excel spreadsheet, as if it was an Access table. You can then use it in SQL